# Disabling form button onClick, and then submitting the form

Tags: javascript, jquery, coffeescript

My form lets users submit a poem.

Sometimes, there's a field for a new user name on that page (if nobody's logged in). In that case, I want to override the button click so that it signs them up first:

```
$('#submit-poem').click ->
  $('input[type=submit]').attr('disabled', true)
  if $('#new_poet_name_field').length
    signUp();  // This will submit the poem form after registering
    false
  else
    console.log("A poet was already logged in!")
    true
```

This used to work fine. But now, when there is no `new_poet_name_field`, the submit button stays disabled. Returning `true` used to submit the form. Now, I have to explicitly do `$('#new_question')[0].submit()` if there is no `poet_name_field`.

Why doesn't the form submit when `true` is returned? My workaround is worrisome; it seems possible that the form might submit twice now: once when I explicitly submit it, and once when `true` is returned.

Comment: Not super relevant, but you risk someone submitting with "enter" or some other key and bypassing your click altogether. Might be neater to hook into the form's "submit" event and return false/true there.

Comment: Show me the HTML, and why isn't there a form when you are suppose to submit it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should bind to the form 'submit' event and use preventDefault/return false when you want someone to sign up instead of submitting the poem.  This way there is no need to do any disabling/enabling of buttons.

Comment: Binding to the submit event worked, that's how it was before I broke it!

Answer (score 0):

I dislike the idea of not having a form. Its invalid and sure to not follow HTML's Specification.

Every constructive form elements should be wrap inside a form tag. You can control the submission of form in more than one way.

---

The code you are using is horrible

1. WHY?? Is there more than one submit button? The code below disables every submit button on the page, which can be of other forms too.

   ```
   $('#submit-poem').click ->
     $('input[type=submit]').attr('disabled', true)
   ```
2. This is wrong way to check the authenticity of submission, it can be easily manipulated with tools like firebug.

   ```
   if $('#new_poet_name_field').length
       signUp();
   ```

---

If finding out if the user is logged in or not that important, then you can quickly send an ajax request to a service page, that gets you that information

```
$('#submit-poem').click(function() {
    $(this).attr('disabled', true)
    $.post("yourservicepage.php", {}, function(data) {
          // RE suppose, data is the boolean value from server indicating logged in or not
          if(data != true) {
             signup(); //if not logged in then signup
          }
          //...
    });
});
```

Comment: I wasn't too clear. There's always a form for `poem`. What I meant was that sometimes there's a field for `poet_name` (if nobody's logged in).

Comment: @bevanb, Check if somebody is logged in, on the basis of SESSIONS in server, not from JS.